# Adding a function call from an external library (rpclib) in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, rpc, llvm-ir

I have a very simple program that takes two integers and adds them together. I want to add a snippet of code into this program so that where `add` function is called it gives user a choice instead to do computation locally or on server.

My original program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" double add(double a, double b);

int main()
{
    double a, b, result;
    cout<<"Enter first argument: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter second argument: ";
    cin>>b;
    result = add(a, b);
    cout<<"Locally computed result: "<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}


extern "C" double add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Desired transformation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rpc/client.h"
#include "rpc/rpc_error.h"

using namespace std;

extern "C" double add(double a, double b);

const int PORT = 20143;

int main()
{
    // Init RPC client
    rpc::client c("localhost", PORT);
    double a, b, result;
    cout<<"Enter first argument: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter second argument: ";
    cin>>b;
    char location;
    cout<<"execute function on server or client? (s/c) ";
    cin>>location;
    if (location == 'c') {
        result = add(a, b);
        cout<<"Locally computed result: "<<result<<endl;
    }
    else if (location == 's') {
        result = c.call("run_on_server", "add", a, b).as<double>();
        cout<<"Response received from edge: "<<result<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

extern "C" double add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I am using [rpclib](http://rpclib.net/) for remote call. I have generated IR with different versions of program to compare them and see what I need to add.

1. A very normal looking IR gets generated for original program
2. If I add rpc headers and `rpc::client c("localhost", PORT);` about 50 lines get added.
3. When I add `result = c.call("run_on_server", "add", a, b).as<double>();` it blows up and adds about 11k lines. I have no idea why though. Shouldn't it have already added everything needed at step 2 where I created the object?

My question is, how do I go about a transformation like this? I can add simple function calls to IR but not sure how I should include rpc headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper function that would do all heavy lifting. Something like

```
extern "C" void helper(const char* funcName)
{
rpc::client c("localhost", PORT);
c.call("run_on_server", funcName);
}
```

Compile this code into a `.bc` file and link it in inside your pass. After that, insert calls to `helper()` wherever you want.

You can use `helper`s code as a sort of template and add required arguments and returned value.

Comment: I followed exact same steps and my transformed bitcode is ready. However, now I want to compile it to an executable but getting a linked error. Can I not use linked IR for anything but transformation?

Comment: Ask a new question and provide error message and code relevant to linking.